# Custom property is null IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've customized `ApplicationUser`. `DotaUserProfile` property is successfully saved in database in another table. But when I'm trying to get this property, for example,

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var profile = user.DotaUserProfile;
```

I'm getting `null`.
Fragments of codes for you to help:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DotaUserProfile DotaUserProfile { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<DotaUserProfile> DotaUserProfile { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Registration code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DotaProfileRegister(DotaProfileRegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var dotaProfile = new DotaUserProfile()
        {
            Nickname = model.Nickname,
            University = model.University,
            RoleInGame = model.RoleInGame,
            HoursInGame = model.HoursInGame
        };
        user.DotaUserProfile = dotaProfile;
        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have added custom properties to the ApplicationUser you must instance the UserManager on a different way.

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyDbContext()));
```

With this manager the properties of your `ApplicationUser` should be loaded.

```
ApplicationUser user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Replace the `MyDbContext` with you're own `DbContext` instance. For more information check the following site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: after your suggested changes my property still null

Comment: Can you try to make it as follow: public virtual DotaUserProfile DotaUserProfile { get; set; }. Take a look at the link there is an example of storing in a different table.

Comment: My source was this article)