# Custom IdentityUser class property/dependent entity is always null

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core targeting NET6.0 using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` user management system with `EntityFrameworkCore`.

I have a custom dependent entity (`Players`) which I want to link to my custom `ApplicationUser` class in a one-to-one relationship. Every `AspNetUsers` record has an associated single record in the previously existing `my_db_schema.tblPlayers` database table. The AspNetCore identity tables are in the same database. Both are populated with real data (This project is to migrate from `AspNetIdentity` to `AspNetCore.Identity`)

```
[Table("tblPlayers", Schema = "my_db_schema")]
    public class Players
    {
        //[Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("User")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

The `UserId` is a foreign key to the `Id` column on the `AspNetUsers` table. The `Id` column is a primary key.

My custom `ApplicationUser` class is defined as this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public Players Players { get; set; }
}
```

In my custom `ApplicationDbContext` `OnModelCreating` function, I have the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<Players>().HasKey(t => t.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasOne<Players>(s => s.Players)
            .WithOne(u => u.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Players>(ad => ad.UserId).HasPrincipalKey<ApplicationUser>(x => x.Id).IsRequired();

}
```

I am not interested in any automatic removal/management of data in the `tblPlayers` database table. I am not interested in running migrations or scaffolding. All that I need is that for any place in my code where I get an instance of an `ApplicationUser`, that the `Players` property is populated with data from the `tblPlayers` database table. No matter what combination of fluid API, or annotations I use, the `ApplicationUser.Players` property is always null, and the rest of the `ApplicationUser` properties are populated as expected.

I have seen these articles:

[Why custom properties for IdentityUser custom class are always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275558/why-custom-properties-for-identityuser-custom-class-are-always-null)

[Custom property is null IdentityUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460748/custom-property-is-null-identityuser)

But both of these require a specific instantiation of the custom `ApplicationUserManager` class. I would like to avoid having to do that in all areas of my code where `ApplicationUserManager` is referenced if possible.

Please help :)

**EDIT: I have implemented my own custom `ApplicationUserManager` already.**

Comment: Players in ApplicationUser has to be declared virtual

Comment: Same with ApplicationUser in Players

Comment: It's working without doing this, based on solution below. Can you advise why I should implement as virtual in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create your own custom `UserManager` in order to do that. But @Mr.T is right, it is necessary to include the dependant table in order to retrieve records filled.

So you have 3 options, except creating a custom `UserManager`:

1. In case you are following the `Repository` pattern you would do something like the following:

```
//Yor 'UserRepository' or whatever
public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetUsers()
{
    var set = _context.Set<ApplicationUser>()
        .Include(user => user.Players);
    
    return await set.ToListAsync();
}
```

2. In case you are using the DbContext directly - you would basically do the same as within the method above.
3. And in case you are using the default `UserManager`:

```
var filledUsers = await _userManager.Users.Include(user => user.Players).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a custom `UserManager` is trivial -

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<User>
```

Then register it at startup

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddUserManager<QuestUserManager>()
```

From there you'll just inject the custom user manager class where you need it.

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
  private readonly CustomUserManager _userManager; 

  public SomeController(CustomUserManager userManager)
  {
    _userManager = userManager;
  }
}
```

The only way you'll get the `Players` property populated is to override the method(s) that return a `User` and add `.Include(u => u.Players)` to the EF Core queries - something like

```
public override async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)

  return await Users.Include(u => u.Players).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I didn't realise until I re-read my question, but I already have implemented a custom `ApplicationUserManager` class. I needed the direction of overriding the functions within to get the desired result.